# Trying to delete rows from a table based on the max value determined by a join with 2 other tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to delete rows from a table based on the max value determined by a join with 2 other tables.  I am receiving the following error:

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

I would appreciate any input.  Thank you.

```
    DELETE d
    FROM MLSURETY.PRINCIPAL d
    WHERE BOND_DTL_ID IN
    (SELECT MAX(BD.BOND_DTL_ID)
    FROM MLSURETY.BOND B
    JOIN MLSURETY.BOND_DETAIL BD ON B.BOND_ID = BD.BOND_ID
    WHERE B.BOND_NUM IN (7900640177, 7900327545)
    GROUP BY B.BOND_NUM, B.BOND_ID);
```

Comment: try using simply 'DELETE MLSURETY.PRINCIPAL ' and then continue with your where

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the `d` is superfluous:

```
DELETE FROM MLSURETY.PRINCIPAL d
. . .
```

`DELETE` syntax has subtle variations from database to database.